# Using Namespaces in Other Projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, namespaces

As the screenshot demonstrates, I have a project `SampleApp` that uses the namespaces `EDAM` and `Thrift`.  I want to replicate the functionalities of `SampleApp` to another project.

Do I have to include the two projects (`EDAM` and `Thrift`) in my other project?  Can I just copy the folders instead of including the actual project files?  Can I just convert them to some sort of DLL or something?

[image]

Comment: Assuming that the other projects are building assemblies (dlls), then you can just reference the DLL from the other project rather than including the source in your project. Even easier if you have them installed in the GAC, then you can just selected them from the assemblies list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't copy the folders, just add references to the projects. Even if the projects are class libraries you don't want to copy the DLLs, instead you should add references, just in case your DLLs are updated:

[How to: Add or Remove References in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: I didn't know I could reference an entire project.  I thought I could only reference DLL files.  How can I do this?  Thanks.

Comment: So, the documentation says, "Projects lists all reusable components created from local projects."  Does this mean I have to have to copy and paste both EDAM and Thrift projects into my new project?

Comment: You reference the entire project. At the end only the compiled output (DLL files) are referenced

Comment: Nope, don't copy and paste. Just add references to those projects. Right there on your project right click on References

Comment: My other project is in a separate solution.  Does that make a difference to your solution?

Comment: No it does not. The solution just groups projects. A project may be part of multiple solutions

Answer (score 4):

You definitely should add references to the EDAM and Thrift projects from the SampleApp project.

To do so, follow these steps:

1. Right click the 'References' folder in the SampleApp project.
2. Select 'Add Reference...'
3. On the popup, go to the 'Solution' tab.
4. Select the EDAM and Thrift projects.

Under no circumstances should you just copy the files.

Comment: How do I add references?  Do you mean I need to copy and paste the entire projects (EDAM and Thrift) into my new project?

Comment: @user1477388 - No. Under SampleApp there's a folder called 'References'. Right click and select 'Add Reference...'

Answer (score 1):

If the "other" project is in the same Solution, you should be able to reference EDAM, Thrift and even SampleApp from that project much in the same way you set the references up for SampleApp.

If this "other" project will be in a new solution...I'd have to do a little research and testing.

Comment: Yes, the "other" project is in another solution.

Comment: I did check into that.

In order to reference a namespace from another solution, that namespace does have to be in a Class Library (aka DLL). 

You can then add a Reference to the DLL in the new project/solution and that will allow you to add a `using` line for the namespace.

Comment: Thanks, Christopher.  I will give it a try.

Comment: **Chris one question:**  When I go to my new solution and click "add refernces" and browse to my folder where I see the solution, I can't find any DLLs for EDAM or Thrift anywhere.  Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Be sure to compile the DLL for Release, and look for it in the bin/Release folder.

You also should be able to find the reference under the Projects tab in the Add Reference dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio project references are equivalent to referencing an assembly directly, but it has a great advantage: when you build a project, Visual Studio take cares of building its dependent projects too.

In addition, Visual Studio will prevent circular references.

There're many other pros, but it's a good summary.

Copy-pasting the code files isn't importing a namespace: this is duplicating code! And referencing the assemblies directly is a waste of time and features!